# Why is this div not null and the almost same div is null

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="List1" style="display:none">
    VIDEO 1</br>
    VIDEO 2</br>
    VIDEO 3</br>
</div>
<div id="List2" style="display:none"> 
    VIDEO 4</br>
    VIDEO 5</br>
    VIDEO 6</br>
</div>
<div id="List3" style="display:none">
    VIDEO 7</br>
    VIDEO 8</br>
    VIDEO 9</br>
</div>
```

This is javascript code I use:

```
    var div = document.getElementById("List"+id);

    if(div == null)
    {
        document.getElementById("List"+id).style.display = "block";
    }
```

Why is div id "List1" not null, and div id "List2", "List3" it is null.

They are almost exactly the same...

Comment: Are you sure you're adding `#List2` and `#List3` to the DOM? (`document.getElementsByTagName("div").length === 3`)

Comment: `</br>` should be `<br>`?

Comment: @Matt Sorry, I'm new to Javascript. I used to code in PHP, what do you mean by adding #List2 and #List3 to the DOM?

Comment: Well if you're creating them via JavaScript, make sure you're adding them to the DOM afterwards. If you don't know what this means though, it means it's probably not applicable to you :). Also, realise you want to check whether the `div` is *not* `null`, so `if (div != null)`.

Comment: `if(div == null)` should be `if(div != null)` - you only want to work on it if it is NOT null.

Comment: @Matt Wow, thank you.. I don't know if that was the problem, but it's working better now. Should I edit it in my original question?

Comment: If it's working now, that's the answer to your question, so feel free to post that solution as an answer. However, this question is really Too Localized, as the problem was a typo rather than an actual code problem; I'd consider deleting the question if you can, as it won't help any future visitors. If you can't, don't worry about it; the close-votes should run their course, and the question will eventually be closed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a0viedo/WWFtV/1/ try this example

Comment: @Matt it actually wasn't the only change i made.. I declared another var div = document.getElementById("List"+id).

Answer (score 0):

As Pulkit [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157890/why-is-this-div-not-null-and-the-almost-same-div-is-null#comment19611291_14157890), it's probably because `</br>` it is not a valid tag in HTML, what you are looking for is `<br />`.

`</br>` is a closing tag of something that you have never opened, hence your whole HTML is unbalanced and not well-formed. Probably your browser is not able to parse it correctly leaving behind a crappy DOM model.

Comment: I would like to see the DOCUMENT TYPE you are using. Not fully sure about this but the browsers might parse the HTML differently based the standard that you declared to be compliant with